# How can I go about live streaming sound on Android?

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I wish to make an app that allows a group of (6-8) people to listen in on a live stream of sound between two other people. How would I go about doing this, and/or is this even possible to do on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something similar to a VOIP call between two people and allow others to listen in on their conversation?

This is not trivial and requires an AudioStream (RTP audio) between the parties and most likely SIP to manage the calls.  You may not want it to look like a conference call between 6 people, with 4 of them muted, but it could be managed that way and the implementation hidden from the users.

I'd suggest looking at some of the open source Android voip projects.